# SQL Query to get the sum distinctly in given condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to get the sum total of a column based on similar column variable only? Please see given example to further understand the problem.

**This is the sample data:**

```
Location    TENANT     Date         Sales     Area
AMALL       Tenant1    1/1/2016   1,000.00    50
AMALL       Tenant1    1/2/2016       0.00    50
AMALL       Tenant1    1/3/2016       0.00    50
So on..

AMALL       Tenant2    1/1/2016     500.00    60
AMALL       Tenant2    1/2/2016       0.00    60
AMALL       Tenant2    1/3/2016       0.00    60
So on..

AMALL       Tenant1    2/1/2016     800.00    50
AMALL       Tenant1    2/2/2016     200.00    50
AMALL       Tenant1    2/3/2016       0.00    50
So on..


AMALL       Tenant3    2/1/2016     600.00    50
AMALL       Tenant3    2/2/2016     600.00    50
AMALL       Tenant3    2/3/2016       0.00    50
So on..
```

As you can see, In one given location, there are two or more different tenants included in it. Each has sales daily. Also, Each tenant has unique Square meter or Area. What I want to achieve is the sample output below.

**Expected Output**

```
Location     Month   Total Sales    Total Area
Amall      January     1,500.00        110
Amall     February     2,200.00        100
```

Please see given expected output. Based on the result 1,500 is the Total Sales for January comprising the sales of TENANT 1 and 2 (1000 + 500 = 1,500), and the total Area comprising only the distinct Area of Tenant 1 and 2 (50 + 60 = 110)

In the month of February, Only Tenants 1 and 3 are the contributors, assuming that Tenant 2 was closed and has no sales at all.

Based on the Total Sales, it is **2,200**, coming from 1000 (Tenant 1) and 1200 (Tenant 3). The Total Area this time Should be **100** (50 from Tenant 1 + 50 from Tenant 3). 60 area value from Tenant 2 is not included of course since it has no sales in the given month (Feb)

**Current, Wrong Output**

```
Location     Month   Total Sales    Total Area
Amall      January     1,500.00        110
Amall     February     2,200.00         50
```

Based on the updated logic and codes applied, I was able to correct the output for January Total Area, using Distinct command on my codes, However I am incorrect in February, having 50 only, it should be 100 since Tenant 1 and Tenant 3 are different tenants and should sum up their individual Area, Since I am using Distinct command, ***the system is treating their Area as one, hence not summing up their Area.***

**How can I be able to still get their sum, since, Area comes from separate or Different Tenant**

**Here is my updated code**

```
SELECT location ,  tenant ,  a.date , sales, area
INTO #Temptable1
FROM  SalesTable



SELECT  tenants.location , months.number  ,months.MonthName 
    ,(sum(case when year(DATE) = 2016  then sales end)) as 'Total Sales'
    ,(sum(Distinct(case when year(DATE) = 2016  then area end))) as 'Total Area'

FROM 
    (       
    SELECT Number , DATENAME(MONTH, '2015-' + CAST(Number as varchar(2)) + '-1')
   'MonthName'
    FROM master..spt_values 
    WHERE Type = 'P' and Number between 1 and 12
    ) months

CROSS JOIN
    (       
    SELECT DISTINCT  locationd ,  location
    FROM #TempTable1
    ) tenants    

LEFT JOIN #TempTable1 t   
ON months.monthname = datename(month,t.date) and tenants.location = t.location 

GROUP BY  months.monthname  , tenants.location , months.number
ORDER BY  datepart(MM,months.monthname + '01 2000');
```

I just incorporated a Distinct command in the last line based on the suggestion of one expert, still answer is not given.

Hoping you share your expert advice on the main problem.

Comment: You can use `DISTINCT` inside `SUM` statement like: `,(sum(DISTINCT case when year(DATE) = 2016  then area end)) as 'Total Area'`

Comment: Hi, that is not enough because in an instance where in a tenant has the same Area with another tenant, the sum of total Area will be compromised as it will not add the correct sum total @gofr1 I will update my question

Comment: I have added example for you @gofr1

Comment: Thanks, indeed I was wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This should work

To be able to test and verify it I created a temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE #Test 
(
Location    varchar(20),
Tenant      varchar(20),
[Date]      date,
Sales       decimal,
Area        int
)

INSERT INTO #TEST
SELECT 'AMALL', 'Tenant1', '1/1/2016', 1000.00, 50
UNION
SELECT 'AMALL', 'Tenant1', '1/2/2016', 0.00, 50
UNION
SELECT 'AMALL', 'Tenant1', '1/3/2016', 0.00, 50
UNION
SELECT 'AMALL', 'Tenant1', '1/4/2016', 0.00, 50
UNION
SELECT 'AMALL', 'Tenant1', '1/5/2016', 0.00, 50
UNION
SELECT 'AMALL', 'Tenant2', '1/1/2016', 500.00, 60
UNION
SELECT 'AMALL', 'Tenant2', '1/2/2016', 0.00, 60
UNION
SELECT 'AMALL', 'Tenant2', '1/3/2016', 0.00, 60
UNION
SELECT 'AMALL', 'Tenant2', '1/4/2016', 0.00, 60
UNION
SELECT 'AMALL', 'Tenant2', '1/5/2016', 0.00, 60
```

New solution, after reviewing comments

```
 ;WITH ATL(Area, Tenant, Location) AS
 (
    SELECT MAX(Area) Area, Tenant, Location 
    FROM #Test 
    GROUP BY Tenant, Location
 ),
 AreaLocation(Area, Location)
 AS
 (
    SELECT SUM(Area) Area, Location
    FROM ATL
    GROUP BY Location
 )
 SELECT
     T.Location,
     DATEPART(MONTH, T.[Date]) Month,
     SUM(T.Sales) [Total Sales],
    MAX(AL.Area) [Total Area]
 FROM
    #Test T
 JOIN
    AreaLocation AL ON T.Location = AL.Location
 GROUP BY
    T.Location, DATEPART(MONTH, [Date])
```

The old solution to the problem:

```
SELECT
    Location,
    DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]) Month,
    SUM(Sales) [Total Sales],
    SUM(DISTINCT Area) [Total Area]
FROM
#Test
GROUP BY
Location, DATEPART(MONTH, [Date])
```

And I also like to drop the table so I can run it again if I make changes

```
DROP TABLE #Test
```

Comment: right! The subquery is unuseful. I'll delete my answer. Your is better

Comment: @JoeTaras Thank you ;)

Comment: Please also note that the distinctness of the Area should be based per Tenant, because there instances where different tenant have the same Area.  For example (T1 = 80, T2 = 80) , total area should be 160 and not 80

Comment: condition is: Area Distinct to one particular tenant. When the same Area is detected but belongs to another or different tenant, it will be counted. @Jonny

Comment: Hi @joeTaras the subquery is intentional because I am using that to segregate a tabular presentation of sales monthly per year.. having YEARS as columns and MONTH as rows

Comment: @rickyProgrammer: I've referred on my answer (now deleted) not your ;)

Comment: I updated my answer to handle multiple tenants with the same area

Comment: Hi, appreciate the update, however, though the answer is correct, still it does not answer the expected problem output. Should it be considered correct answer? As you can see in the problem, the monthly sales total sales and total area is considered.

Comment: the output is getting the over all sum of Area, BUT DO NOT CONSIDER monthly sales. @Jonny

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question with additional dummy data as an example. Hope question is clearer now @Jonny

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to reproduce this problem:

```
;WITH Temptable1 AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('AMALL', 'Tenant1', '1/1/2016', 1000.00, 50),
('AMALL', 'Tenant1', '1/2/2016', 0.00, 50),
('AMALL', 'Tenant1', '1/3/2016', 0.00, 50),
('AMALL', 'Tenant2', '1/1/2016', 500.00, 60),
('AMALL', 'Tenant2', '1/2/2016', 0.00, 60),
('AMALL', 'Tenant2', '1/3/2016', 0.00, 60),
('AMALL', 'Tenant1', '2/1/2016', 800.00, 50),
('AMALL', 'Tenant1', '2/2/2016', 200.00, 50),
('AMALL', 'Tenant1', '2/3/2016', 0.00, 50),
('AMALL', 'Tenant3', '2/1/2016', 600.00, 50),
('AMALL', 'Tenant3', '2/2/2016', 600.00, 50),
('AMALL', 'Tenant3', '2/3/2016', 0.00, 50)
) as t([location], tenant, [date], sales, area)
)

SELECT  tenants.location , months.number  ,months.MonthName 
    ,(sum(case when year(DATE) = 2016  then sales end)) as 'Total Sales'
    ,(sum(Distinct(case when year(DATE) = 2016  then area end))) as 'Total Area'

FROM 
    (       
    SELECT Number , DATENAME(MONTH, '2015-' + CAST(Number as varchar(2)) + '-1')
   'MonthName'
    FROM master..spt_values 
    WHERE Type = 'P' and Number between 1 and 12
    ) months

CROSS JOIN
    (       
    SELECT DISTINCT  location
    FROM TempTable1
    ) tenants    

LEFT JOIN TempTable1 t   
ON months.monthname = datename(month,t.date) and tenants.location = t.location 

GROUP BY  months.monthname  , tenants.location , months.number
ORDER BY  datepart(MM,months.monthname + '01 2000');
```

And I got:

```
location    number  MonthName   Total Sales Total Area
AMALL       1       January     1500.00     110
AMALL       2       February    2200.00     50
AMALL       3       March       NULL        NULL
...
AMALL       12      December    NULL        NULL
```

In February there must be `100` and we get only `50` with `DISTINCT`. My bad.

So I remove `DISTINCT` and add CTE to get areas you need:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  [location],
        tenant,
        area,
        DATEPART(month,[date]) as m,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [location], tenant, DATEPART(month,[date]) ORDER BY [date]) as rn
FROM Temptable1
)

SELECT  res.*,
        SUM(c.area) as [Total Area]
FROM (
SELECT  tenants.[location],
        months.number,
        months.[MonthName],
        SUM(case when year(DATE) = 2016  then t.sales end) as [Total Sales]
FROM 
    (       
    SELECT  Number,
            DATENAME(MONTH, '2015-' + CAST(Number as varchar(2)) + '-1')as [MonthName]
    FROM master..spt_values 
    WHERE Type = 'P' and Number between 1 and 12
    ) months
CROSS JOIN
    (       
    SELECT DISTINCT [location]
    FROM TempTable1
    ) tenants    
LEFT JOIN TempTable1 t   
    ON months.[monthname] = datename(month,t.[date]) and tenants.[location] = t.[location]
GROUP BY  months.[monthname]  , tenants.[location] , months.number
) as res
OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE [location] = res.location and m = res.number and rn= 1) as c
GROUP BY res.[location], res.number,res.[MonthName]
   ,res.[Total Sales]
ORDER BY datepart(MM,res.[monthname] + '01 2000');
```

This CTE produce this:

```
location    tenant  area    m   rn
AMALL       Tenant1 50      1   1 --we need this area
AMALL       Tenant1 50      1   2
AMALL       Tenant1 50      1   3
AMALL       Tenant1 50      2   1 --and this
AMALL       Tenant1 50      2   2
AMALL       Tenant1 50      2   3
AMALL       Tenant2 60      1   1 --and this
AMALL       Tenant2 60      1   2
AMALL       Tenant2 60      1   3
AMALL       Tenant3 50      2   1 -- and this
AMALL       Tenant3 50      2   2
AMALL       Tenant3 50      2   3
```

All with `rn = 1`. Then JOIN (OUTER APPLY) this CTE with your result and output:

```
location    number  MonthName   Total Sales Total Area
AMALL       1       January     1500.00     110
AMALL       2       February    2200.00     100
...
```

Comment: Hi! would just like to say that I have used your concept ion getting the answer or code that I want...

Comment: But the Outer is more complicated and was not able to run the code successfully, but your idea / concept is so brilliant that I was able to understand it and apply in my own logic. Should I still mark your answer an answer?

Comment: Great that you solved your problem! I think you should mark your answer as accepted - your solution is much simpler and clearer than mine (it is overkill I guess)!

Comment: Thanks, and without you, and your idea of partition I will not get into the simpler solution, so thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

Based from GOFR1 answer, that is very helpful, I was able to get the answer by just including two lines of code from my existing codes..

```
SELECT location ,  tenant ,  a.date , sales, area,
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY location, tenantcode,  DATEPART(month,[date]) ORDER BY a.date) as rn
INTO #Temptable1
FROM  SalesTable





SELECT  tenants.location , months.number  ,months.MonthName 
    ,(sum(case when year(DATE) = 2016  then sales end)) as 'Total Sales'
    ,(sum(case when year(DATE) =2016 and rn = 1 then area end)) as 'Total Area'

FROM 
    (       
    SELECT Number , DATENAME(MONTH, '2015-' + CAST(Number as varchar(2)) + '-1')
   'MonthName'
    FROM master..spt_values 
    WHERE Type = 'P' and Number between 1 and 12
    ) months

CROSS JOIN
    (       
    SELECT DISTINCT  locationd ,  location
    FROM #TempTable1
    ) tenants    

LEFT JOIN #TempTable1 t   
ON months.monthname = datename(month,t.date) and tenants.location = t.location 

GROUP BY  months.monthname  , tenants.location , months.number
ORDER BY  datepart(MM,months.monthname + '01 2000');
```

**Just added these lines**

1. , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY location, tenantcode,  DATEPART(month,[date]) ORDER BY a.date) as rn

added that column based from the idea of Gofr1

2. ,(sum(case when year(t.DATE) = @Year1 and rn = 1 then t.sqm end)) as 'Total Area'

replacing

(sum(distinct((case when year(DATE) = 2016 then t.sqm end)))) as 'Total Area'

and it worked

Answer (score 1):

This expression truncates the date to a month boundary:

```
DECLARE @VarStart date = '2001-01-01';
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, @VarStart, [date]), @VarStart)
```

You can use any starting date that is the first day of the month.
The same approach can be used to truncate date to any other boundary (week, day, hour, minute, etc.)

It is not wise to rely on the fact that different tenants have different area in your sample data.

Calculate monthly totals separately, then join them together on Location and Month.

`CTE_MonthlySales` calculates total sales per Location per month.

`CTE_TenantAreas` returns area for each tenant that had at least one sale within a month. This is grouped further in `CTE_MonthlyAreas` to get total area that had sales within a month.

`CTE_Months` generates a list of months.

`CTE_Locations` is a list of all distinct locations.

Final `SELECT` (left) joins everything together.

```
WITH
CTE_MonthlySales
AS
(
    SELECT
        Location
        ,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, @VarStart, [date]), @VarStart) AS DateMonth
        ,SUM(Sales) AS TotalSales
    FROM #TempTable1
    GROUP BY
        Location
        ,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, @VarStart, [date]), @VarStart)
)
,CTE_TenantAreas
AS
(
    SELECT
        Location
        ,Tenant
        ,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, @VarStart, [date]), @VarStart) AS DateMonth
        ,MIN(Area) AS TenantArea
    FROM #TempTable1
    WHERE Sales <> 0
    GROUP BY
        Location
        ,Tenant
        ,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, @VarStart, [date]), @VarStart)
)
,CTE_MonthlyAreas
AS
(
    SELECT
        Location
        ,DateMonth
        ,SUM(TenantArea) AS TotalArea
    FROM CTE_TenantAreas
    GROUP BY
        Location
        ,DateMonth
)
,CTE_Months
AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(month, Number-1, '2016-01-01') AS DateMonth
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE Type = 'P' and Number between 1 and 12
)
,CTE_Locations
AS
(
    SELECT
        Location
    FROM #TempTable1
    GROUP BY
        Location
)
SELECT
    CTE_Locations.Location
    ,CTE_Months.DateMonth
    ,ISNULL(CTE_MonthlySales.TotalSales, 0) AS TotalSales
    ,ISNULL(CTE_MonthlyAreas.TotalArea, 0) AS TotalArea
FROM
    CTE_Months
    CROSS JOIN CTE_Locations
    LEFT JOIN CTE_MonthlySales
        ON  CTE_MonthlySales.Location = CTE_Locations.Location
        AND CTE_MonthlySales.DateMonth = CTE_Months.DateMonth
    LEFT JOIN CTE_MonthlyAreas
        ON  CTE_MonthlyAreas.Location = CTE_Locations.Location
        AND CTE_MonthlyAreas.DateMonth = CTE_Months.DateMonth
ORDER BY
    CTE_Locations.Location
    ,CTE_Months.DateMonth
;
```

Comment: DATEPART is easier than the calculation

Comment: @Jonny, with `DATEPART` you have to think about years and sorting. In general, it is easier to deal with normal full dates, rather than date parts. With dates you can easily sort them when period is, say, from Nov til Feb next year. You can have a period that covers more than a year, say, 27 months.